# CSS: Div's position

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working with the wordpress theme, it generates the html output of comments automatically. 
The HTML output is like:

```
Author says:
August 30, 2011 at 6:43 pm  (Edit)
The comment text...
Reply.
```

I need to change the position of the elements. For example, I would like to display the author, date/edit and reply on one line.
like:

```
Author says:    August 30, 2011 at 6:43 pm  (Edit)  Reply
The comment text...
```

As I said above, I can not change the HTML structure, so I need to change the positions of elements with CSS only. However I'm uable to do so.
I'll appriciate any help.

**Here is the generated html:**

```
<div class="comment-body" id="div-comment-33">

        <div class="comment-author vcard">
            <img width="48" height="48" class="avatar avatar-48 photo" src="http://i55.tinypic.com/21buau9.jpg" alt="">     

            <cite class="fn">
                <a class="url" rel="external nofollow" href="#">Author</a>
            </cite> 
            <span class="says">says:</span>     

        </div>

        <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
            <a href="#comment-33">August 30, 2011 at 6:43 pm</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a title="Edit comment" href="#" class="comment-edit-link">(Edit)</a>       
        </div>

        <p>The comment text...</p>

        <div class="reply">Reply</div>
</div>
```

**jsFiddle link:**

http://jsfiddle.net/GLwfW/1/

PS. I know we can change the HTML output by adding custom function in wordpress, but that's not an option.

Comment: You have the ability to edit the HTML directly via the **Edit** menu on your dashboard. **Dashboard > Appearance > Edit. Then select `comments.php` file, find the html that displays the comment & comment author and move the html that displays the author, date/edit and reply onto one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with `display:inline-block;` on the first few elements:

```
.comment-body{
    border:1px solid green;
    position:relative;
}

.comment-author, .comment-meta{
    display:inline-block;
}

.reply{
    position:absolute;
    top:34px;
    left:360px;
}
```

Then give a `position:absolute;` to the `.reply`.  You may need to fiddle with these numbers.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/GLwfW/9/

---

**EDIT**

Based on @Diodeus's comment re

> You can try absolute positioning -- until the author's name is long,
>   which will then force "reply" to be on top of the text that was
>   normally to the left of it.

One thing to do is `detach` the reply from the DOM and re-insert it.  So

**New CSS**

```
.comment-body{
    border:1px solid green;
    position:relative;
}

.comment-author, .comment-meta, .reply{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Some JS**

```
var a = $('div.reply').detach();

a.appendTo('.comment-meta');
```

**Revised Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/GLwfW/10/

Comment: The tricky part is that he wants the "Reply" moved up next to edit.

Comment: Totally right @JamesMontagne.  I just edited to fix that.  Have a look.

Comment: You can try absolute positioning -- until the author's name is long, which will then force "reply" to be on top of the text that was normally to the left of it.

Comment: Probably the only solution due to the order of the elements, but if the author's name is longer this won't work.  I guess you could decide what the longest possible name is and position based on that or something, all kind of messy though.

Comment: True @Diodeus.  Two options here, I think.  One, limit the length of the autthor's name or remove the reply from the DOM and reinsert it at the proper place for easy styling.

Comment: It's wordpress - if you could limit the author's name, you could just edit the code and rearrange the HTML instead.

Comment: Answer revised to include a jQuery fix @Diodeus

Answer (score 2):

You can change the position of the items, by adding "float:left", but this will not work in this case because you need the reply to appear before "The comment text". CSS cannot rearrage the ORDER of the elements.

When "painted into a corner" like this, you can always re-write the HTML on the client using jQuery. Brutal but sometimes that's the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css

```
.comment-author, .comment-meta  { display:inline; }
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLwfW/4/)

Edit: Seens I missed the reply button. It can be placed absolutely in the top right corner. With:

```
.comment-body{ position:relative; }
.reply { right:0; top:0; position:absolute; }
```

But that could overlap the text if the text got to long. Otherwise you would have to change the html.

Comment: He is wanting the reply link up there as well.

Answer (score 1):

This will be very difficult, there is a way but it's very limited. If you can guarantee the pixel height of the actual comment body (which I presume you can't) then you can inline the elements, take the `reply` element out of the flow (positioning it at the bottom of the container) and set a padding on the container to force it down. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLwfW/8/) for an example. It achieves the desired effect but won't hold up well to multi-line comments.